# Discord bot delete command

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

My main goal is for someone with message managing permissions to type a command for deleting a message but be able to specify how many messages they'd like to delete.

I have tried messing with variables but I don't have much knowledge on them, usually ending in some errors. I've tried replacing the value of messages deleted (the 2) with the variable with success but I'm clueless when it comes to changing the variable with a message.

```js
 if(message.member.hasPermission('MANAGE_MESSAGES')) {
                        if(message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}delete`)) {
                        message.channel.bulkDelete(2)
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I will suppose you have it on message event.

This is one of many ways you can do it:

```js
if(message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}delete`)) {
      const user = message.mentions.users.first();
      // Parse Amount
      const amount = !!parseInt(message.content.split(' ')[1]) ? parseInt(message.content.split(' ')[1]) : parseInt(message.content.split(' ')[2])
      //Check if it the amount for message to delete where declared
      if (!amount) return message.reply('Must specify an amount to delete!').then(msg => msg.delete(15000));
      // Fetch 100 messages (will be filtered and lowered up to max amount requested)
      message.channel.fetchMessages({
        limit: 100,
      }).then((messages) => {
          //I declare the messages like that with amount + 1 to delete the command itself
          messages = messages.array().slice(0, amount + 1);
          //And finally buldDelete deletes the desired amount
          message.channel.bulkDelete(messages).then(messages => console.log(`Bulk deleted ${args[0]} messages`))
            .catch(console.error);


      });
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to split message.content, which will return an array that I'll name *args* for this example. Then, *args[1]* should be the number you are looking for.

```
const prefix = '@' 
const args = message.content.split(' ')

    if(message.member.hasPermission('MANAGE_MESSAGES')) {
                            if(message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}delete`)) {
                            message.channel.bulkDelete(args[1])
                            }
                        }
```

Et voilà ! You just need to make sure that *args[1]* is a number now.